# Geting data from RIA services in viewmodel of silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ria

i am creating silverlight application and implementing MVVM pattern. in my view model i want to get data from RIA service domain class. through following code

```
LoadOperation<DimensionDTO> loadOp = this.parametersDomainContext.Load(this.parametersDomainContext.GetDimensionDTOQuery());
List<DimensionDTO>  Dimensions = LoadOperation.Entities as List<DimensionDTO> ;
```

though RIA service is returning data but in second line debugger shows entity count = 0

according to me this is because of asynchronous calling of RIA service. before return of data from ria service second line is executed. how can i make these two line synchronous. i mean second line should be executed when load operation is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your View Model

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<DimensionDTO> GetDimensionDTOs()
{
  return this.ObjectContext.DimensionDTOs;
}
```

in your Silverlight Code

```
DomainService1 DS = new DomainService1();
LoadOperation<DimensionDTO> loadOp  = DS.Load(DS.GetDimensionDTOsQuery());
loadOp.Entities ; // for Assign to IEnumerable<DimensionDTO>
```

or

```
    loadOp.Completed += new EventHandler((s,e)=>{
      for(DimensionDTO item in loadOp.Entities )
      {
        // add entity to your list for  List<DimensionDTO>
      }
    });
```